# How to set multiple parameters with one method on PreparedStatement

Tags: java, jdbc

Is it possible to set multiple parameters in a single method call of a `PreparedStatement`? I can't find an operation, using Java 1.6.

Something like this:

```
// This query takes multiple input parameters
PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO MY_TABLE (COLUMN1, COLUMN2, COLUMN3, COLUMN4, COLUMN5) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");

// I would like to set all at once
ps.setMultipleParameters("USERNAME", 789, new Date(), 9999L, null);
```

I am looking for a way to ease writing integration tests, since I can copy the parameters list and just paste in the test.

Comment: whats wrong with setting them individually?

Comment: @Reimeus nothing. just trying to save some time copy/pasting from autogenerated statements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dont think the jdbc API has such a method, but you can easily write a method to do that, e.g.

```
 public static void setParameters(PreparedStatement statement, Object... parameters) throws SQLException {
    for (int i=0; i < parameters.length; i++) {
        statement.setObject(i, parameters[i]);
    }
}
```

However, read the javadoc of PreparedStatement.setObject(..) to see what restrictions applies to the types of Parameters.